# drag and drop picturebox between forms

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

what is the best way to do this  y need move a picturebox and drop in the other form y used this for move my picture

```
private void pictureBox2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
         x = e.X;
         y = e.Y;
     }
 }

private void pictureBox2_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)  
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        pictureBox2.Left += (e.X -x);
        pictureBox2.Top += (e.Y - y);
    }
 }
```

Comment: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=179

Comment: Moving a control from one form to another requires changing its Parent property.  You need to consider using Drag and Drop for this, well supported in Winforms.

Comment: @CAbbott: how about a more modern link? That one is from .NET 1.1.

Comment: Please don't tack things like " c#" on to the ends of your titles. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: @CAbbott: yes, but if you send people to a .NET 1.1 link, they'll follow other links from there, winding up in a little maze of twisty passages, all ancient.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use the Drag and Drop eventing.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dragdrop.aspx

A good article describing nearly exactly what I believe you're trying to do is here:
http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2002/11/11/dragdrop.htm

Hope that helps.